# Lecture video of how to get machine learning to work in practice

Tags: machine-learning, references

I remember that Andrew Ng had a very good lecture were he explained how to get Machine learning to work in practice. If I remember correctly, it was a lecture video companying the following slides:

http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/ML-advice.pdf

I have not been able to find the talk/lecture video again. I was wondering if anyone knew where it was or had a link to it or had a copy to it?

Comment: @Silverfish I would consider a proper reference question to be "help me find resources on some topic" rather than asking about a single link - this is a question to Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew Ng has lectures on ML on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning), which includes a section of suggestions for applications.

There are also Stanford lecture videos on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ8T9b-uGVE). I have linked the video you seek.

Comment: u sure its there? I already tried looking there. I could have sworn I saw it somewhere...

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm absolutely certain it has sections about considerations for applications.

Comment: I already knew he talked about it in https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/week/6 but its not a talk where he uses the exact slides I posted. I am sure he gave a talk using the exact slides I posted.

Comment: @CharlieParker I have linked the exact video you seek since you could not find it for some reason.

Comment: Yeessss, they should title their videos better. Thanks.